# Leaf underside browning on Baby Rubber Plant (Peperomia Obtusifolia)

Tags: watering, fungus, browning, peperomia

Recently I've noticed that my Baby Rubber Plant has some weird brown spots on some older/lower leaves. They look fine (albeit a bit yellow) from the top, but their underside is making me slightly worried.

Is this an infection of some sort (fungus?) or am I just watering it too often?

The entire plant, with the leaves visible:
[image: Full image]

A suspicious leaf, top side:
[image: Suspicious leaf, top]

Same leaf, underside:
[image: Suspicious leaf, under]

Another leaf, underside:
[image]

P.S.: Realized the leaves were a bit dusty, wiped them off right after taking the photos.

Answer (score 1):

Peperomias like dry warm environments. Their thick waxy leaves are a great protection against insects and diseases. The roots are subject to fungus attack when they don't drain sufficiently rapidly. The shiny protective leaf surfaces defend against insect attack, so they are in many ways armour plated. The spots are likely from some kind of mechanical damage when young and soft, such as being knocked against something pointed; a little bleeding of sap may happen and this dries on the surface and oxidizes the sugars. They don't like direct hot sun or intense light. Discoloration of the lower leaves is nothing to be concerned about, a natural aging of the leaf as it completes its life cycle. Keep the roots on the dry side.